# Can the Dispel Magic spell stop the effects of divination spells?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, divination

Alright, so my question, related to [this one](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/147088/53060) is: Could a player use [*Dispel Magic*](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Dispel%20Magic#content) to end the effect of a divination spell, if detected?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Yes, if the divination spell places something within range for them to target

Provided they know there is a magical effect within range, they can cast Dispel Magic on it.

Detect Magic states:

> Choose one creature, object, or magical effect within range. [...]

In particular, as it does not require you to be able to see the effect, you can target invisible creatures, objects and magical effects. You simply need to know it is within range in order to target it.

Additionally your DM may require you to direct the Dispel Magic in a particular direction, and if you choose the wrong one you will fail to "hit" it.